# Can Google's AJAX API feeds be custom animated?

Tags: ajax, rss, google-feed-api

Has anyone had any luck customizing the feed animation? Ideally I would like a left-right marquee animation.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just use [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) or similar to animate the div where you [feeds will be displayed](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/#FEEDCONTROL). Also check the examples on the Google Ajax Feeds page.